# How to do I use %s in a mysql query without errors

Tags: python, mysql, select

I am having some trouble selecting from my database using python to execute a MySql query. I have tried two methods to achieve this, but both methods have returned the error shown below:

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1`

What Id like to do is return the row count (which is always zero or one) when a username parameter is passed. I have looked at other examples where people have had this issue but I cant find a good fix.

The first method I tried was this:

```
def check_data(username):
    sql = """SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_user WHERE username = %s"""
    mycursor.execute(sql, username)
    #do something with the data
```

I then tried using `SELECT (CASE WHEN (uname = %s) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS IsEmtpy FROM tbl_user limit 1;`

This works database side, but still throws the same error when run in the application. I tried wrapping the %s like '%s' but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation for `.execute`, or looking for examples using a search engine? On the web pages that you found, did it tell you anything interesting about the type of data that should be passed for the arguments? When you "looked at other examples where people have had this issue", can you show some of the examples that you found? Did you try reading the answers that were given to those people? Did you understand those answers? Why do you think they are not applicable to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing enclosing the string between quotes (singles or doubles).
You can check the query you're executing by printing it before the `mycursor.execute` statement, but basically you're sending MySQL something like `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_user WHERE username = foobar`.

Try fixing it with `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '%s'`.

On a side note, your approach is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should check the documentation of the tool you're using to connect to the DBMS for "prepared statements".

Comment: Notice that the OP *is* using (or at least trying to use...) a parametrized query, not string interpolation.